# wpf dependency property trigger issue

Tags: wpf, binding, dependencies, dependency-properties

Am a newbie!
I have a problem in working with dependency property.
for example, I have small project like below, with a text box in main window and usercontrol with textblock , button and string dependency property.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy1vw.png)

Mainwindow textbox is linked to usercontrol's textblock (yellow color) through dependency property as like

```
<Window x:Class="dp1.MainWindow" ....
  >
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="txt" Text="d"></TextBox>
    <local:Uc1 prop1="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=Text}"></local:Uc1>
</StackPanel>
```

the usercontrol's button just assign some random string to the dependency property. code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            prop1 = new Random().Next().ToString();
        }
```

1) while running, whatever I type in textbox, it is reflecting in the yellow textblock with NO Issue. refer above image1
2) I clicked the button, it assigned some text with no Issue. refer image2
3) Now, I start typing in the textbox and the issue comes where the text is not updating/reflecting to usercontrol textblock. refer Image3

Image2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQq9v.png)

Image3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdLlG.png)

Can anyone please help me!

Comment: The Binding must be set to TwoWay mode: `prop1="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"`. You can make TwoWay the default binding mode by setting `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` when you register the dependency property.

Comment: Thanks Clemens for your prompt reply. The Actual issue is that the  flow should from Main window to usercontrol but not in bidirectional. the above example is simplified version of my actual project where instead of string, am using business model dependency property.

Comment: When the actual issue is something different, why don't you mention that in your question in the first place? Please try to explain it as precise as possible. Don't show anything simplified that doesn't resemble your problem.